# how to properly install coverage mode?

Tags: ruby-mode

What I did

- downloaded https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trezona-lecomte/coverage/master/coverage.el
  to load path ( ~/.emacs.d/lisp/ )
- added to bottom of init.el:

  (use-package coverage
  :ensure t)

What I got:

- opened a .rb file
- M-x coverage-mode
- in *Messages*:

  cond: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, (lines . [1 1 1 nil 1 0 0 nil 0 0 ...])
  Error running timer ‘coverage-redraw-buffers’: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p (lines . [1 1 1 nil 1 0 0 nil 0 0 nil nil nil])) [6 times]

Comment: Have you configured `coverage-mode`? Have you run coverage on your .rb file? Are the results in the location that `coverage-mode` is expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent developments have actually broken this package.
[One workaround is to pin the version of simplecov in your Gemfile to an older version](https://github.com/trezona-lecomte/coverage/issues/13#issuecomment-644786809).